# Converting a Map to a List in Scala without map keys?

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, scala-collections, mutable

How can I convert a map to a list without the map keys being involved in the list in scala?

```
val mp = collection.mutable.Map[Long, String]()
mp(0) = "val0"
mp(1) = "val1"
mp(2) = "val2"
mp.toList //I want: List("val0", "val1", "val2")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for

```
mp.values.toList
```